# Loading databases dynamically in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My application uses Codeigniter 3.X and I'm trying to use different DBs for each of my user.

So the main db is main_db and if a user with user id 1 logs in then I want to use db_1 and so on.

Codeigniter allows me to use multiple DBs but I want to achieve this dynamically.

Is there a way to load DBs dynamically in codeigniter? If yes then how?

I have included my database.php below and I load the database in model construct as

```
$this->load->database();
```

**database.php**

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'main_db',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

Comment: If the databases are within the same mysql instance, then there is no need to load them separately, you just need to reference the tables as dbname.fieldname in your queries.

Comment: @Shadow Okay I think that should solve my problem.

Comment: @Shadow this means that I will have to change every query in the source code to add dbname.tablename. This will not be possible as the source code is not small.

Comment: @Shadow finally implementing the way forward suggested by you.